# Need drools workflow examples and tutorial material

Tags: workflow, drools

In my current project, i need to use drools so, any one can help about some sample workflows with examples and the tutorials also.

Thanks in advance!

Regards'
Hari

Answer (score 3):

Best is to simply start with the Drools Flow manual:
https://hudson.jboss.org/hudson/job/drools/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/target/docs/drools-flow/html/index.html

Lots of other useful information in the blog entries:
http://blog.athico.com/search/label/Drools%20Flow

and some examples can be found here:
http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossrules/trunk/drools-examples/drools-examples-drl/

and here as part of the unit tests (Process*Test.java):
http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossrules/trunk/drools-compiler/src/test/java/org/drools/integrationtests/

Kris

Comment: Hi Kris,
Thanks for the information!!

I have requirement about employee exit process, so i would like to write a workflow for this. 

Can anyone provide some examples about the mentioned requirement?

Hari